# Mobile Broadband Connection terminating automatically after 2-3 minutes

Tags: 12.04, mobile-broadband

I am connecting my mobile device with Ubuntu to access INTERNET, It connects easily but after 2-3 minutes it automatically disconnect and then I have to disconnect my mobile device and then reconnect it again to establish a connection. Cant understand what is the problem. No problem with my device as it works flawless with windows.

As asked here is more info:
Device is Samsung wave 575
Network Provider is Vodafone
and Ubuntu is 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and as far as I can tell there should be no compatibility issues with the phone or network. However, IF you are on a prepaid plan, the terms of service state tethering is not allowed, which would likely be your problem. Even with a contract plan, only specific plans allow tethering so make sure you are on one of those plans.
Beyond this my only suggestion is to run an update on your phone. 
Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Delete the connection name (i'm sure it is in the network manager somewhere)
2. Add back the connection (whatever the connection)
3. Restart
4. Re-connect

It's what i do everytime.

Comment: what do you mean by everytime ?